# React does not wait for the data to be read from the api and returns undefined after run package.json script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to create a sitemap by running the package.json script command during build, but it doesn't wait for the data I call from the api and it runs quickly.
The data is returned in the log, but it is undefined in the final result.

***Package.json***

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "build:staging": "env-cmd -f ./.env.staging react-scripts sitemap build",
        "sitemap": "babel-node ./src/utils/sitemapBuilder.js"
    },
```

***sitemapBuilder:***

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Generator from 'react-router-sitemap-generator';
import { allPages } from './GetRoutes';

console.log('=>', allPages)  // undefined


const AllRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" />
        <Route path="/about" />
        <Route path="/contact" />
        <Route path="/blog" />
        {allPages?.map(page => (
          <Route path={page} />
        ))}
    </Switch>
  )
}

const generator = new Generator('url', AllRoutes(), {
  lastmod: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10),
  changefreq: 'monthly',
  priority: 0.8,
});

generator.save('public/sitemap.xml');
```

***GetRoutes:***

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

  let allPages;

  const getAllPages = async () => {
    await axios.get(`url`).then((res) => {
       allPages = res.data.data.map(page => `/${page?.slug}`);
       console.log('allPages: ', allPages) // data return successfully 
      });
    }
  
    getAllPages();

  
  export {
    allPages 
  };
```

I want the final result of a sitemap file to be created in the public folder before the build like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>url/</loc>
    <lastmod>2022-06-04</lastmod>
  </url>
<url>
    <loc>url/about</loc>
    <lastmod>2022-06-04</lastmod>
  </url>
<url>
    <loc>url/contact</loc>
    <lastmod>2022-06-04</lastmod>
  </url>
<url>
    <loc>url/blog</loc>
    <lastmod>2022-06-04</lastmod>
  </url>
<url>
    <loc>url/dynamic-route-1</loc>
    <lastmod>2022-06-04</lastmod>
  </url>
<url>
    <loc>url/dynamic-route-2</loc>
    <lastmod>2022-06-04</lastmod>
  </url>
<url>
    <loc>url/dynamic-route-3</loc>
    <lastmod>2022-06-04</lastmod>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

**Please guide me**

Answer (score 0):

**React doesn't care when untracked data changes.**

It is seeing that `allPages` is being exported from `GetRoutes.js` as a variable with no value. It is mapping over `allPages` (which is still nothing), and you are getting the result you see.

The only way to see anything once the API request resolves is by storing the data in React `state`. By storing the data in `state`, upon it changing it will cause a repaint of the component that is rendering this data.

Comment: Yes, I completely understand, but when I use hooks, I get the error message: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: In addition, this file does not have a life cycle because it does not render anything

In the **SitemapBuilder** file, a series of commands are executed in sequence only to create the **sitemap.xml**, and if you pay attention, this file works separately from the main body of the app and is executed by babel-node and it is in the route **./src/utils/sitemapBuilder.js** and has nothing to do with the main routing of the site.

Comment: Fixed problem with a setTimeout in the **_SitemapBuilder_** file

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but just know that this won't always work and it won't work for everybody. You're hoping that the API will respond within the timeframe of the `setTimeout` and it may not sometimes depending on internet speeds.